# indexing in solr lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing, solr, search-engine

I have a site in which users can post some questions, so I a have a table in mysql like this

> question_id, user_id, tags, views, creation_date

what I want is to be able to

- perform searches which will return question_ids based on those
  **tags**

  and order them by

  1. Views
  2. date, (like newest, or this week, month)
- or searches for a **specified user** and return question_ids again
  ordered by views and date.

In what way should I bring everything in solr, as far as indexing is concerned?
Will I have to index tags, views, date? What should I index so that I have maximal performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about, if using lucene/solr is relay a benefit for you. I don't wanna be misunderstood, but if you like to search inside an  column user_id for an specific user ID, you don't need a addition fulltext-search engine.

Anyway - maybe you only like to have an little project to "play with" solr.
So here are the answers of your questions:

> In what way should I bring everything in solr, as far as indexing is
> concerned?

Put everything to solr/lucene, you need to search for. Use the DHI (data import handler) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler to let solr walk trough your table and index the data.

> Will I have to index tags, views, date?

Yes. You have to index all the things you like to work with.
btw: there is a difference between indexing and storing data. You can index fields (like tags, user_id, views,..) but you don't need to store them (additional) inside your lucene index. Storing data is necessary, if lucene/solr have to return/deliver the searched data.
Otherwise, solr only returns the uniqueKey (primary key) of the matches documents and you have to fetch the data from the datebes (...where pk=< lucene result >)
So you don't need to store those fields, which are only relevant for sorting (for example).

> What should I index so that I have maximal performance?

Index only those fields (columns), you need to work with (solr). Don't index field you will never ask for / search for.

Comment: Ok, I understand there is no need to search for userIDs. But as for the first part, if solr creates inverted indexes of those tags and after a query it finds for example 30000 question_ids, and I want from solr to sort them by views, so that I get for example only from 800th to 900th question_id, how could I have maximal performance? Is the answer by indexing tags, views and store questions_ids so that I can look them up in mysql? Will the indexing of views, assure that it doesn't take forever, so that the question_ids are sorted?

Comment: about your performance concerns. I use lucene index with about 1. million documents. Searching for an frequent keyword, getting 90.000 hits, sorting them by relevancy and boosting by date, returning the first 30 results needs - at all - less than 50ms. If there is an (subquery)cache-hit, normally it needs less than 10ms. Finally it depends on your document size. But i never realized sorting as an performance issue.

Comment: >> it finds for example 30000 question_ids, and I want from solr to sort them by views, so that I get for example only from 800th to 900th question_id<<  <- sorting does not reduce number of documents (from 30.000 to 800-900). sorting only changes the order. but of course, you can filter your results. You should try, what is faster: taking from solr/lucene stored results or load the from database. If your lucene search returns in 10ms, so your DB Access would be the bottleneck. But normally, data at DB could be better handled as data from lucene.

Comment: no I meant from from those 30000 only the 800th to 900th, and not for example from the first to the 100th result, like for example in google when you hit the 12th page.  thanks by the way

Comment: using solr, you can define (for every search) an offset and the number of documents (rows), you like to get. so if your page contain 20hits/results, so you offset is 0,20,40 end so on. With 30.000 documents you will not notice any performance issue between the query time for the 1st or the 12th page.